# MariaDB error on startup, keeps restarting

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu, drupal, mariadb

Suddenly there is this MariaDB error when trying to start my mariadb container after pushing an update to my drupal container via docker. The container keeps restaring over and over again. I rolled back the drupal update but the error persists and i also tried removing the mariadb image and rebuilding it, also no success, same error.

I researched and found out that there is a similar bug related to Mac/Win Systems after an MariaDB update but 
1) i am using and ubuntu 16 system
2) i didnt update MariaDB

Link to the issue: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-16015

Any ideas?

```
2019-11-25  9:47:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './development/cache_update.ibd' with space ID 2698. Another data file called ./development/#sql-ib2713.ibd exists with the same space ID.
2019-11-25  9:47:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 36 pages from redo log.
2019-11-25  9:47:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-25  9:47:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-25  9:47:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-25  9:47:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: preallocating 12582912 bytes for file ./ibtmp1 failed with error 28
2019-11-25  9:47:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not set the file size of './ibtmp1'. Probably out of disk space
2019-11-25  9:47:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create the shared innodb_temporary
2019-11-25  9:47:31 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2019-11-25  9:47:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2019-11-25  9:47:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2019-11-25  9:47:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-11-25  9:47:36 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-11-25  9:47:36 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-11-25  9:47:36 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-25  9:47:36 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2019-11-25  9:47:36 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2019-11-25 09:48:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server  started.
2019-11-25 09:48:37+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2019-11-25 09:48:37+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server  started.
2019-11-25  9:48:37 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.4.10-MariaDB-1:10.4.10+maria~bionic) starting as process 1 ...
2019-11-25  9:48:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-11-25  9:48:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-11-25  9:48:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-25  9:48:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-25  9:48:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-25  9:48:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-25  9:48:37 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2019-11-25  9:48:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-11-25  9:48:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-25  9:48:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-11-25  9:48:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=11785883154
2019-11-25  9:48:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './development/#sql-ib2713.ibd' with space ID 2698. Another data file called ./development/cache_update.ibd exists with the same space ID.
2019-11-25  9:48:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Ignoring data file './development/cache_update.ibd' with space ID 2698. Another data file called ./development/#sql-ib2713.ibd exists with the same space ID.
2019-11-25  9:48:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 36 pages from redo log.
2019-11-25  9:48:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-25  9:48:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-25  9:48:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-25  9:48:38 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: preallocating 12582912 bytes for file ./ibtmp1 failed with error 28
2019-11-25  9:48:38 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not set the file size of './ibtmp1'. Probably out of disk space
2019-11-25  9:48:38 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create the shared innodb_temporary
2019-11-25  9:48:38 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2019-11-25  9:48:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2019-11-25  9:48:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2019-11-25  9:48:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-11-25  9:48:43 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2019-11-25  9:48:43 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2019-11-25  9:48:43 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-25  9:48:43 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2019-11-25  9:48:43 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109315/unknown-unsupported-storage-engine-innodb)

Comment: Nevermind i found the solution just now. Thanks anyway @LinPy :)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, i found the solution. I thought i had enough disk space left but i actually had not.

Here is the solution: https://superuser.com/questions/1267663/docker-mariadb-instance-not-starting-after-update

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this a bit.
The problem was not my *computer* disk memory, but my *docker image memory*.
Deleting some old images and/or running `docker system prune` might help, but if you can afford it you can just increase the Docker memory:

On the Docker Desktop app, go to `Preferences > Resources > Advance > Disk image size`.
Bump up the memory and click on `Apply & Restart`