# XAMPP Table doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql, mariadb, xampp

My XAMPP MariaDB Server version `10.1.25` started to give the below error:

```
2023-01-17 06:44:27 2894 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2023-01-17  6:44:27 10388 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2023-01-17  6:44:27 10388 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2023-01-17  6:44:27 10388 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2023-01-17  6:44:27 10388 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-01-17  6:44:27 10388 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2023-01-17  6:44:27 10388 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2023-01-17  6:44:27 10388 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2023-01-17  6:44:27 10388 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2023-01-17  6:44:27 10388 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-01-17  6:44:28 10388 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found.
InnoDB: If you are attempting downgrade from MySQL 5.7.9 or later,
InnoDB: please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-downgrading.html
InnoDB: If this error appears when you are creating an InnoDB database,
InnoDB: the problem may be that during an earlier attempt you managed
InnoDB: to create the InnoDB data files, but log file creation failed.
InnoDB: If that is the case, please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-creating-innodb.html
2023-01-17  6:44:28 10388 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2023-01-17  6:44:28 10388 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-01-17  6:44:28 10388 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-01-17  6:44:28 10388 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2023-01-17  6:44:28 10388 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Many answers in Stackoverflow (for example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109315/unknown-unsupported-storage-engine-innodb)) suggest that one need to delete the below two files to fix the issue. I have tried this, and it is not resolving the issue.

```
Directory of C:\xampp\mysql\data

17/01/2023  07:01 AM         5 120 KB ib_logfile0
17/01/2023  06:57 AM         5 120 KB ib_logfile1
```

After deleting the above two files, below is the new error message I am getting:

```
2023-01-17 06:49:55 31d4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2023-01-17  6:49:55 12756 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2023-01-17  6:49:55 12756 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2023-01-17  6:49:55 12756 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2023-01-17  6:49:55 12756 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-01-17  6:49:55 12756 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2023-01-17  6:49:55 12756 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2023-01-17  6:49:55 12756 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2023-01-17  6:49:55 12756 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2023-01-17  6:49:55 12756 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-01-17  6:49:57 12756 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB
2023-01-17  6:49:57 12756 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
2023-01-17  6:49:57 12756 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2023-01-17  6:49:57 12756 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=1835037
2023-01-17  6:49:58 12756 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2023-01-17 06:49:58 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 7 log sequence number 232553005
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:49:59 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 3 log sequence number 70739093
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:49:59 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 2 log sequence number 232483374
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:49:59 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 4 log sequence number 232531211
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
2023-01-17 06:50:13 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 445 log sequence number 232218940
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:13 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 701 log sequence number 232019451
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:13 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 294 log sequence number 232486422
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:13 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 446 log sequence number 232321628
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:13 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 472 log sequence number 232486422
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:13 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 295 log sequence number 232534073
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:13 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 594 log sequence number 231435202
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:13 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 586 log sequence number 232534073
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:13 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 296 log sequence number 232534542
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:13 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 448 log sequence number 230791860
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:13 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 612 log sequence number 232534542
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:13 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 297 log sequence number 232019769
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:13 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 449 log sequence number 232323345
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:14 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 475 log sequence number 232019769
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:14 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 298 log sequence number 232486596
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:14 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 556 log sequence number 231655896
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:14 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 507 log sequence number 232486596
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:14 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 299 log sequence number 232535690
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:14 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 451 log sequence number 232224957
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:14 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 478 log sequence number 232535690
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:14 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 300 log sequence number 232536181
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:14 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 452 log sequence number 232327916
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:14 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 497 log sequence number 232536181
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:14 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 0 log sequence number 232553557
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:14 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 8 log sequence number 216476348
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:14 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 571 log sequence number 232553782
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:15 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 10 log sequence number 228464372
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:15 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 401 log sequence number 180666434
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:15 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 12 log sequence number 225103355
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:15 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 543 log sequence number 180666554
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:15 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 303 log sequence number 227174050
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:15 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 674 log sequence number 228494038
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:15 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 304 log sequence number 227748682
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:15 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 700 log sequence number 228469859
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:15 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 570 log sequence number 216476348
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:15 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 637 log sequence number 228494050
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:16 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 502 log sequence number 228493402
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:16 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 501 log sequence number 228476889
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:16 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 500 log sequence number 208097705
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:16 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 509 log sequence number 206651573
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835532.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:16 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 591 log sequence number 181272104
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835542.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:16 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 344 log sequence number 181160222
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835542.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:16 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 601 log sequence number 181207626
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835542.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:16 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 602 log sequence number 64012821
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835542.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:17 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 524 log sequence number 125325406
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835542.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:17 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 547 log sequence number 171759243
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835542.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:17 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 554 log sequence number 180591830
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835542.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:17 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 557 log sequence number 181307591
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835542.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:17 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 513 log sequence number 207294594
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835542.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:17 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 516 log sequence number 225461553
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835542.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:17 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 530 log sequence number 226833102
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835542.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:17 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 527 log sequence number 226833102
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835542.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:17 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 528 log sequence number 228026911
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835542.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:17 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 529 log sequence number 228493540
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835542.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17 06:50:17 31d4 InnoDB: Error: page 537 log sequence number 232553719
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 1835542.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2023-01-17  6:50:17 12756 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2023-01-17  6:50:17 12756 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
InnoDB: Error: trying to access update undo rec field 120 in index "CLUST_IND" of table "SYS_TABLES"
InnoDB: but index has only 10 fields
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com
InnoDB: Run also CHECK TABLE "SYS_TABLES"
InnoDB: n_fields = 97, i = 1, ptr 07BAE8F9
230117  6:50:17 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

2023-01-17  6:50:17 12756 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-82.0 started; log sequence number 1835532
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.25-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=1001
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 787107 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
2023-01-17  6:50:18 396 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
```

I then go ahead and renamed the below file as suggested in many answers here in Stakeoverflow. This file was successfully recreated on starting up the MySQL service.

```
Directory of C:\xampp\mysql\data

17/01/2023  07:01 AM        75 776 KB ibdata1
```

This allowed me to successfully start the MySQL Server without any errors. However, one issue I am now experiencing is that all my databases tables does not exist any more in the tablespace. Below is the specific error message I am receiving if I try to access any tables in any database:

```
use dolibarr7;    
select * from llx_user;
```

```
ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table 'dolibarr7.llx_user' doesn't exist in engine
```

Where `dolibarr7` is an example of the database that I am connect to, and `llx_user` is the table I am trying to access.

Has anyone managed to resolve this before? I have tried solutions suggested at [Xampp-mysql - "Table doesn't exist in engine" #1932](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759870/xampp-mysql-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine-1932). This does not work in my case.

Comment: So I guess you failed to read all my comments on every answer linked that said it was a bad idea in the linked answer. Did you even keep a backup? If you play with MariaDB files directly you will end up with the ever worsening situation you describe. I recommend upgrading to a MariaDB version above 10.6 (don't know the xampp version) and restoring your tables from backup.

Comment: @danblack Unfortunately, there is no backup. The mysql -> backup folder only contains files last modified in the year 2018. Restoring this is causing the error to go away, but then I do not have the most important asset which are the recent databases on this machine.

Comment: It can't be important if the last backup was made five years ago. Is the binary log enabled and if yes, are the binary log files from 2018 until today available?